# how to properly configure samba access using groups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, file-sharing

I am having trouble trying to get a specific group to access samba server through windows.

is it possible to allow certain groups to the file sharing server?

example, I have a group called "engineering" within in that group, i have user1 and user2. so how would I only make the engineering group access samba server through the credentials when prompted in windows:?

thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have your Unix group set up correctly, you should be able to use a share configuration similar to the following:

```
[ShareName]
path = /path/to/share
guest ok = no
guest only = no
write list = @engineering
read list = 
valid users = @engineering
```

The `@` sign before the name of the group tells samba that this is a group name instead of a user name.

If you're allowing the group write access through samba, but you are still having trouble writing to the share (but you can authenticate correctly) then you should check file permissions and your `force user` and `force group` options.  These can be set globally or per-share.

If this doesn't help, you should provide more information about the trouble you're running into.

Comment: thnka you very much i am going to test it out now!